# How can I execute ng test for all components of sub modul of Angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-runner

I have my angular app, declared like this:

app.module.ts

```
export class AppModule {}
```

for which I can run tests with `ng test MyApp`

Within this app, I have multiple modules, declared like this:

my-one.module.ts / my-other.module.ts

```
export class MyOneModule {}

export class MyOtherModule {}
```

These are imported in AppModule.

How can I do something like `ng test MyOneModule` / `ng test MyOtherModule`, with which I'd like to **run just the tests of all components in that very "sub module"** instead of all tests in the app?

I couldn't find information in the [official docu](https://angular.io/cli/test) or here in StackOverflow. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Yes I know the only allowed arguments of ng test are either an app or a library.

Comment: Jasie I think you will find my answer more satisfying
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149258/how-can-i-execute-ng-test-for-all-components-of-sub-modul-of-angular-app/71575382#answer-71575382

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using this workaround:

In `test.ts` I change the path:

```
const context: any = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

to

```
const context: any = require.context('./app/modules/my-one-module', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

or

```
const context: any = require.context('./app/modules/my-other-module', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

This causes `ng test` to just execute the tests in the defined directory (and its sub directories).

Not ideal, as I don't like to make changes to checked-in files, that are not meant to be committed, but it does the job.

Comment: Is there a way to execute the tests of more than one module using this same approach? For example if I want to execute 'my-one-module' tests and 'my-other-module' tests in the same execution how it would be?

Comment: with my solution not possible, afaik :-/ you can just do one after the other by changing the path.

Answer (score 1):

You can test each module seperately without the need for any code changes.

Dublicate test.ts and tsconfig.spec.json files for moduleone and rename like following;

> test.moduleone.ts
>
> tsconfig.moduleone.spec.json

find and change test.ts to test.moduleone.ts in tsconfig.moduleone.spec.json

```
"files": [
   "test.moduleone.ts"
]
```

find and change path as moduleone path in test.moduleone.ts;

```
const context: any = require.context('./app/moduleone', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

run tests for moduleone like this;

```
ng test --main src/test.moduleone.ts --ts-config src/tsconfig.moduleone.spec.json
```

You can add script for each module to scripts section in package.json

```
"scripts":{
   "moduleone_tests":"ng test --main src/test.moduleone.ts --ts-config src/tsconfig.moduleone.spec.json"
}
```

so you can test each module with a simple command like

```
npm run moduleone_tests
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find some resources online, [such as this one](https://gist.github.com/KidkArolis/fd5c0da60a5b748d54b2), that explains how to grep files to run only them.

I also remember a coworker running his tests from intelliJ for a single file, and there was a command line argument, but I don't recall it at all.

Finally, you can also use `fdescribe/xdescribe` and `fit/xit` on the tests to run those ones only.

Comment: You also have the `exclude` property to exclude files by using your karma configuration file. More information here : http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/configuration-file.html

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of fdescribe and fit, but this will not allow running all tests *of all components* that belong to the sub module. (I updated the description.) I'll try your links.

Comment: @jasie since it's unit testing, you won't be able to test all of the components of a module with a single file. If it's what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: The app does just that ;-) (execute all unit tests of all components in the app, with 'ng test MyApp') Are we misunderstanding each other?

Comment: @jasie running `ng test MyApp` run **all spec files of your application**. It is different than running *a single module with its components* : for instance, you can not run `ng test MyLazyLoadedModule` and expect this module and its components to be tested. See the difference ?

Comment: Yes I see the difference. I posted my question because of this very difference. I hoped it can be achieved with another command or configuration.

Comment: @jasie I've seen your own answer, that's indeed one of the ways to do it. Hope it gets a feature soon, I'm interested in it too ! (You can make a github issue for it on the Karma repo, just in case)